# Can vegetable plants do well if planted within the lighted area near a (LED) mercury vapor light?

Tags: plant-health, vegetables, growth, container-gardening, sunlight

Due to mobility (and other) issues, I can't just put the veggies I want to grow into the ground. I need them to be at a level which doesn't require bending. In the past, I've used "dead refrigerators" (filled with dirt) as elevated planters; but, the (LED) "mercury vapor light" wasn't an issue back then. NOW, the only place I have to set some up are within the the "range" of that light, which is up on my power pole and comes on automatically.

I'm wanting to plant (primarily) yellow and zucchini squash, spaghetti squash, sweet potatoes, green cabbage, green peas, carrots, tomatoes, peppers (bell, banana and Anaheim), onions, garlic, ginger, and cantaloupe. I (also) have some heirloom corn seeds; but, an earlier post I read indicated that it would probably do fine, even if I planted it right under the power pole. There seemed to be conflicting opinions regarding the tomato and pepper plants.

All these plants are "heirloom;" and, if the supply chain gets so disrupted that food becomes hard to get (financially or otherwise) I want to "have my 6 covered." About the only area I could set up to grow away from the light would be in an area which would also be shaded from afternoon sun light.

In many ways, I'm quite a novice at this; so, any suggestions would be useful. (Probably to a lot of other folks as well, given the state of things right now...)

Answer (score 1):

Mercury vapor in not an LED. Mercury vapor puts out a very narrow/limited light spectrum . As I remember the light frequency is not in any range used by chlorophyll so will have no affect on plants.

Comment: While I certainly hope that you're right on this, my electric company sent someone out with a bucket truck,  a couple of years back, to change out the old style bulb to the new style they were replacing them all with. The guy who changed it CALLED IT a LED and touted it as an improvement. It is brighter than the old one. I'll call CVEC on Mon. to confirm what he called it and report back what they tell me. Thank you. :)

Comment: UPDATE: My electric company wasn't a lot of help; since, they order their "security lights" from wherever they can get the best price at the time... The lady I talked to was able to tell from my account that it was a 48 watt LED bulb, which was installed on 06/17/17. I already knew that it had a "dusk to dawn" sensor on it, the same as my old mercury vapor light. They have no record of the manufacturer ~ which is probably an important point in finding out its light spectrum. Still trying to catch anyone in the warehouse, to see if they can tell me more. It is @25~30' AGL w/@ a 100' radius.